# How to make a w3.css navbar not overlay the section title when linking

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navbar, w3.css

I am using the  `w3-top` tag to fix the `navbar` to the top of the page, even if the user is scrolling down. Some links in the `navbar` link to sections of the current page. However, if the user is linked to such a section, the fixed `navbar` overlays the section title (since both are displayed at the top of the screen).

In essence I want the link to go a few px above the section title or some other way, so that the title is visible.

The navbar in question:

```
<div class="w3-top">
<div class="w3-bar navbar">
    <a href="thinkcorner.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-small">ThinkCorner</a>
    <a href="index.html#Landing"><img src="img/logo-sm.png" class="w3-left" style="max-width:50px"></a>
    <a href="index.html#Kontakt" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-small">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="index.html#Team"class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-small">Team</a>
    <a href="index.html#Erfahrungen"class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-small">Erfahrungen</a>
    <a href="index.html#Kompetenzen"class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-small">Kompetenzen</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium" onclick="shorter()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

The .css property for the navbar:

```
.navbar {
color:#grey;
background-color:white;
opacity:0.9;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 2px solid #600;
padding: 12px; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you are linking just by using ids. You can use javascript and set a offset for the top when scrolling down to the specific section to avoid your navbar overlapping the section title.

Here’s an example of how to accomplish just that 
https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2

Comment: Thank you! I understand that "offset" is used go get the top and left coordinates of the element I want to link to. However, how would I add something to the top coordinate before it is taken by the scrolling function? Something like: "link to that elements coordinates, but add 20px to the top coordinate"?

Answer (score 0):

Give the section title a padding-top of some pixels. For eg,

```
<h1 id="sectionTitle">This is some title</h1>
```

If h1 has a padding-top of say 50px, you will get some spacing above the title. Hence the navbar won't overlap the title.

Comment: True, but It would mess up the layout. I am looking for something that would leave the current style intact and just arrange around the navbar.